# Tapi code for analog phone line

Tags: vb.net, telephony, tapi

I have Bell phone line which is analog not digital. I am able to send faxes through windows fax and scan software provided by Microsoft but my tapi application, which works fine with digital lines (like magic Jack), is not working with my Bell phone line. I wonder is there any special code or trick that can work for dialing phone? My point is when Windows Fax and scan software is working on same line than why my application is not working. I have tried couple of application of third party tool but no success.
Any help would appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add T prefix before you dialing number to set mode into Tone and send analog not digital signal.

```
TCountry(AreaCode)SubscriberNumber
```